# Get-Command missing in Powershell after installing Version 4

Tags: powershell, installation

Something must have gone wrong by installing dot net framework 4.5 and Powershell 4.0

I tried repair install of framework 4.5 and even deinstallation and reinstallation, but it doesn't help.

```
PS D:\Var\bin> get-command

get-command : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ get-command
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Command], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand


PS D:\Var\bin> $psversiontable

Name                           Value                                                          
----                           -----                                                          
PSVersion                      4.0                                                            
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                            
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                        
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18408                                                
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2                                                            

PS D:\Var\bin> $Error.FullyQualifiedErrorId
System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
```

Comment: The command get-command is from the dll: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll Can you check if you have that DLL and maybe import one from a working instance of powershell?

Comment: In my Windows / System I find this dll with Version 6.3.96.0016406. In a working Windows 8.1 VM I have Version 6.3.9701.0. But I do not know how to import a dll into GAC

Comment: This is for a single Windows 8.1 machine?

Comment: No the Problem is on a single Windows 7 machine

Comment: Did you by any chance installed preview version of WMF on it? I recall something similar to that when I installed final WMF over preview...

Comment: No preview versions where installed -- and copying the dll from the W 8.1 installation didn't help. I plan to install Windows 7 in a Virtual Box VM and to update it to dot.net framework 4.5 und Powershell 4.0 next days

Comment: Just installed a second user on the machine and in his profile all is fine